# Use diffrent javascript files in Laravel blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I'm creating an app with Laravel 7 and I want to have common js files imported in the main layout and specific js file imported in each view, or use the script tag directly. My Code looks like this:

Layout body

```
<body>
  <main>
    @yield('content')
  </main>
  
  <script src="{{ asset('js/common.js') }}"></script>
  @stack('script')
</body>
```

And one of the files looks like this:

```
@section('content')
  <div class="game-version-list">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($list as $element)
        <li>
          <a href="{{ route($element['name']) }}">{{ $element['text'] }}</a>
          <div>
            <span class="info-btn" data-key="{{ $element['key'] }}">?</span>
            <div class="game-info"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endsection

@push('script')
{{-- <script src="{{ asset('js/common.js') }}"></script> --}}
<script>
  
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  btns.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', getGameInfoMobile);
  });
  
</script>
@endpush
```

When I load the page it tells me that the function getGameInfoMobile is not defined (the function is in the common.js file).

I've tried also to import the common file in the stack but there's no difference, it only works if I put evereything in the common.js file.

I don't what to import the all script file in the app.js and I really need this approach because there are a lot of function that I need to use multiple times. Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you show how you defined `getGameInfoMobile`?

Comment: Its defined just like: function getGameInfoMobile(){ //code}, also i will need to pass some arguments to the function, I just didn't get there yet.

Comment: I'm not good with Laravel. Are you sure this ` @stack('script')` will make sure every script in your templates will be at this place after `common.js`?

Comment: It should insert the script in the push section where is placed the @stack. But it's only a problem of the eventListener that can't see the function